# Why is there device information missing after Hybrid Azure joined?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-hybrid-connections

I have successfully have my device showing as 'Hybrid Azure AD joined' but the Owner is now blank. How do you get the to populate again?

[image]

Comment: Is your device Win 10? It seems to be a known issue. It's strongly recommended to vote this post: https://microsoftintune.uservoice.com/forums/291681-ideas/suggestions/32360305-azure-ad-hybrid-joined-windows-10-devices-should-r on User Voice to get more attention of the Product Group.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 devices that are hybrid Azure AD joined don't show up under USER devices. Use the All devices view in the Azure portal. You can also use a PowerShell [Get-MsolDevice](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/msonline/get-msoldevice?view=azureadps-1.0) cmdlet.

**Only the following devices are listed under USER devices:**

1. All personal devices that aren't hybrid Azure AD joined.
2. All non-Windows 10 or Windows Server 2016 devices.
3. All non-Windows devices.

Reference [document.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/devices/faq#q-i-registered-the-device-recently-why-cant-i-see-the-device-under-my-user-info-in-the-azure-portal-or-why-is-the-device-owner-marked-as-na-for-hybrid-azure-active-directory-azure-ad-joined-devices)